# How to change status of one component inside v-for without affecting other component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a `childComponent` which is rendered dynamically via `v-for` inside of the `parentComponent`. Inside the Parent component I have some logic that fetches data from the database and displays it on the screen. The fetch request query is bases on the child component selected (clicked on). Once the user has clicked on a component I would like to show the user that the data is loading by changing text inside the child component to `loading`. The issue I'm facing is that when the request has been sent, all children components generated by `v-for` change status to "Loading...". I would only like the once that has been clicked to change.

Edit: [Added CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/dynamic-components-loading-kyicvi?file=/src/components/childComponent.vue)

I created a simple representation of my problem.

parentComponent.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <childComponent
      v-for="(element, index) in 3"
      :key="index"
      :data="index"
      :loading="loading"
      @click-from-child="clickedEvent"
    />
    <p>{{ returnedData }}</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import childComponent from "./childComponent";
export default {
  components: { childComponent },
  data() {
    return {
      loading: false,
      returnedData: "",
    };
  },
  methods: {
    clickedEvent(componentData) {
      this.loading = true;
      this.returnedData = "";
      console.log(`Request Sent to: ${componentData}`);
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("Request Completed - Success");
        this.returnedData = `Some Data returned from: ${componentData}`;
        this.loading = false;
      }, 3000);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

childComponent.vue

```
<template>
  <p v-if="loading">LOADING...</p>
  <p v-else @click="triggerMethod">Click Me</p>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    data: {
      type: Number,
    },
    loading: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    },
  },
  methods: {
    triggerMethod() {
      const customURL = `getDataURL/data=${this.data}`;
      this.$emit("click-from-child", customURL);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to pass index as `loading` prop instead of boolean:

```js
Vue.component('childComponent', {
  template: `
    <div>
      <p v-if="loading === data">LOADING...</p>
      <p v-else @click="triggerMethod">Click Me</p>
    </div> 
  `,
  props: {
    data: {
      type: Number,
    },
    loading: {
      type: Number,
      default: null,
    },
  },
  methods: {
    triggerMethod() {
      const customURL = `getDataURL/data=${this.data}`;
      this.$emit("click-from-child", customURL);
    },
  },
})
new Vue({
  el: "#demo",
  data() {
    return {
      loading: null,
      returnedData: "",
    };
  },
  methods: {
    clickedEvent(componentData) {
      this.loading = componentData;
      this.returnedData = "";
      console.log(`Request Sent to: ${componentData}`);
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("Request Completed - Success");
        this.returnedData = `Some Data returned from: ${componentData}`;
        this.loading = null;
      }, 3000);
    },
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <child-component
      v-for="(element, index) in 3"
      :key="index"
      :data="index"
      :loading="loading"
      @click-from-child="clickedEvent(index)"
   ></child-component>
   <p>{{ returnedData }}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. 
This indeed works, but you have moved the data fetching method inside the `childComponent`.
The example here is a simple representation of a problem I'm facing in a large app where the fetching has to be done outside the `childComponent`.

Comment: @babis95 hey mate, I didn't move anything, just copied your code from codesandbox, fatching is still in parent component. The point is not to use boolean but index or id for loading prop. :) [take a look at your demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/dynamic-components-loading-forked-ueo5ud?file=/src/components/parentComponent.vue)

Comment: thanks again for taking time to help me with this. Sorry, I read the code wrong. You are right nothing was changed, my bad. It all works. Thanks again!!